# How to perform do-release-upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 once 16.04 was already released?

Tags: 15.04, 15.10, do-release-upgrade

I have a machine running 15.04, and while trying to use `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade it I realised it is forcing me to get 16.04 which I don't want because I know that our code doesn't work well with the updated Python on 16.04.

How can I do this upgrade? (console only)

#### Update

It seems that even doing an upgrade to current version doesn't work anymore!!

```
 An upgrade from 'vivid' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool.
```

#### Update: it seems that `do-release-upgrade -d` did upgrade to 15.10 even if it had the impression that it would upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: 15.10 reached end of life yesterday and is no longer supported.

Comment: @ByteCommander No longer supported means that we are in deep.... If it's not possible to upgrade to it, please make it an answer and put a link to document that explains it.

Comment: What Byte is trying to say is we cannot help you. We don't support unsupported releases. You can ask on [unix.se], which accepts dev builds and EOL versions.

Comment: If Python is your only problem, you could also install a custom Python build in 16.04 (be careful not to mess up the system Python versions though).

Comment: @ByteCommander I am aware about this approach and that's to be considered. Still it seems to be a serious issue not be able to perform this upgrade.

Comment: You *could* upgrade (or reinstall) to 15.10 somehow, but it is not recommended and we do not support EOL releases here on this site. Just think of all the security updates you would not get.

Comment: Please check my update: the problem seems to be bigger: even upgrading to current LTS doesn't work anymore!

Comment: There is no direct upgrade path from 15.04 to 16.04, you must go over 15.10 first. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release#

Comment: This is the top search result on Google for "upgrade from vivid to xenial not supported with this tool".  As someone who is trying to resurrect an old 15.04 machine without reinstalling, this question is both on-topic and useful.

Comment: For a stack Exchange whose name is AskUbuntu this is a comment that sounds disturbingly like "sorry you are screwed".   I am sure there are plenty of ordinary desktop users who do not upgrade every time there's a new release (because we are not sysadmins, we are people with jobs and families and obligations),

To say flatly, sorry we can't help you, seems to undermine the entire purpose of this site.   I have been part of several stack exchange sites and I have never seen that attitude displayed.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @chrisfs +1. People want to get back on track and this is an emergency procedure if you missed the date. You could at least post the update as an answer. I almost overlooked the solution.

Comment: `do-release-upgrade -d` worked ok for me to upgrade to 15.10. Just had to update then to 16.04 and finally to 16.10. Up to date at last haha !

Comment: How can this be off topic because its an old version not supported anymore? What about all our old questions, should these now be purged from Ask Ubuntu? Closing this question was quite plain and simple an idiotic idea. I need to know the answer to this question and if I discover it first would like to reply. By the way adding -d is not the answer to the question what ever the OP thinks.

Comment: For me `do-release-upgrade -d` did not work. It told me `No new release found`. I was able to go forward by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` replacing `vivid` with `wily` and then doing `apt update` and `apt dist-upgrade`. After that I was able to proceed to 16.04 with `do-release-upgrade`. Note that if your Ubuntu mirror does not have the required files any more, you can find another mirror which still has the old version available. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ is one such option. Going forward from 16.04 to 16.10 non-lts I needed to edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

Comment: @snap 's should be the accepted answer.